# Nginx redirect without a server name

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server, https

I'm serving a webpage from an embedded linux box that may or may not be connected to the internet. The idea is, a user enters the IP of the machine and the page comes up. I want to redirect all non-ssl urls to an ssl url (https). Every example I've found uses $server_name or $host in the `return` line of the nginx configuration. The problem for me is that the IP of the machine might change and editing the nginx config file every time is not an option. I've tried setting the server_name to `_` to no avail. What does work is if I set `server_name` to the current IP of the machine. Then, if I type in `192.168.1.196` it redirects to `https://192.168.1.196/dashboard`, which is what I want. Unfortunately this will not work in production, since as mentioned the IP may change. My current nginx config is below.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    #server_name  _;
    #server_name 192.168.1.196;
    ssl_certificate server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key private.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    autoindex on;
    return 302 https://$server_name/dashboard;

    location /dashboard {
        alias build;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can  you provide some more details about your configuration files, directories, and possibly a curl command output?

Answer (score 1):

Then it's `$host` that you want to use, because this is what contains the Host: header that the browser supplied.

Comment: Tried this, does not redirect.

Comment: Then you should start from there and try to figure out why.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out why for the past few hours, that's why I came here.